# Kendo ComboBoxFor does not bind on post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've this kendo *ComboBoxFor* and when I send a post request it does not bind, it sends its value as null.

Here is view model

```
public class FormViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Form Name")]
    public string FormName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Module")]
    public List<ModuleList> ModuleLists { get; set; } 

}

public class ModuleList
{
    public int? ModuleId;
    public string ModuleName;
}
```

Here is my post controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create(FormViewModel form)
 {
    try
    {
        {
            var model = new PMSForm()
            {
                ModuleId = form.ModuleId,
                FormName = form.FormName
            };
            db.PMSForms.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(form);
    }
```

And here is my Kandocomboxfor:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ModuleLists)
                  .DataTextField("ModuleName")
                  .DataValueField("Id")
                  .DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("GetModuleList", "PmsModule")))
                  .Placeholder("Select Module...")
                  .Suggest(true)
                  .HighlightFirst(true)
                )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
```

The model does not validate and on debug I found the even though I've selected value in drop down on post I receive null value.

**edit**

I've even tried the dropdown of kendo but even that does not work

```
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Id)
                          .DataTextField("ModuleName")
                          .DataValueField("Id")
                          .BindTo(Model.ModuleLists)
                )
```

Comment: Does your code in the `try`  statement need to be in its own block?

Comment: @AustinWBryan I'm sorry didn't get your point

Comment: You cannot bind to a complex object or collection of complex objects (`ModuleLists`) The property your binding to needs to be `string`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'd tried that and even I'd used model=>model.Id, but in that case combobox does not show any thing, same thing happens

Comment: Then that suggest a problem with `.DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("GetModuleList", "PmsModule")))` Suggest you just hard code a few values for testing - `dataSource: { data: [ { id: 1, ModuleName: "One"}, { id: 2, ModuleName: "Two" } ]` (and your models suggest you should be binding to `ModuleId`, not `Id`)

Comment: Your `try` block has another block inside it. `try { { /* statements */ } return } // end try`. What is the point of this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no the ninding with dropdown and combo are fine but when I select a value and post it. that is the one which create the problem please take a look at the link [HERE](http://prntscr.com/a3uxj9)

Comment: @AustinWBryan nothing there was a condition but I removed that, that has nothing to do with it on post it just does not bind the data to the post method

Comment: @StephenMuecke here is the link of dropdown and data is coming from db [LINK](http://prntscr.com/a3uybj)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Data bind with combo is not an issue on post it does not bind it with the model here see please data is coming from db [link](http://prntscr.com/a3uz6l)

Comment: If your wanting to bind to `ModuleId `, then its needs to be `@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.ModuleId)`. And I also suggest you use you browser tools to inspect want is being posted to check that it is actually a valid value for `short`

Comment: And your also have `.DataValueField("Id")` but the data your returning does not have a property `Id` - it needs to needs to be `.DataValueField("ModuleId")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that can not be because the actual table in db that I'm bind it with is "Id" not module Id, as I said the bind with combo is not issue when I select a value and post it to the ViewModel it does not validate it as you saw in the first link I send you, the moduleId appears to be null which should not be happening

Comment: @StephenMuecke and even after doing what you just said the model still gets null moduleId on post event

Comment: The use you browser tools to inspect what is actually being sent for `ModuleId` when you submit the form.

Comment: I've done that it send only the textbox value and nothing more no Id of the value selected in dropddown or combobox

Comment: [Link](http://prntscr.com/a3v32c)

Comment: Have you changed it to `.DataValueField("ModuleId")`? One of your previous images clear showed that the data your getting has a property named `ModuleId` (not `Id`). And test it my adding a hardcoded data source as per my earlier comments

Comment: Yes I've that but no response same thing, I'd changed at that time when you said that  @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then check `ModelState` in the POST method to see if there is an associated validation error for property `ModuleId`

Comment: it can not be null because that is why it does not pass throw the model state give "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" during debugging if I place the value if moduleId it moves smoothly and saves the value if not this error appears

Comment: hey @StephenMuecke can I say what if I don't have to use the kendo horse **** how can I use simple razor syntax combobox

Comment: If you have populated the `ModuleLists` property, then just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModuleId, new SelectList(Model.ModuleLists, "ModuleId", "ModuleName"), "Select Module...") @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ModuleId)`

Comment: The Bind list does show 4 records in this case but this error happened DataBinding: 'ProjectManagementSystem.ViewModel.ModuleList' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'. or with ModuleId too

Comment: Your property is `public List<ModuleList> ModuleLists { get; set; }` and `ModuleList` contains a property `ModuleId` so it must be `ModuleId` (not `Id`) and you would not get that error using `"ModuleId"` (Note also your properties should have `{ get; set; }` - they are just fields at the moment)

Comment: s***,s***s***s***s*** that was the main issue `{get; set; } .. O God it took 15 hours to solve this thanks Love @StephenMuecke 
Thank you for your help and time [Stephen](http://prntscr.com/a3ve5j) please put that as and answer so that I can mark that as one

Comment: Did it also solve the issue for the `Kendo` control? (not sure it would have made any difference since your `GetModuleList()` method seemed to be returning the correct data based on one of your previous issues). And the reason it didn't work for `new SelectList(..)` is that the method uses reflection to look up property names (fields are excluded).

Comment: Yes! It is working fine with kendo controls, let me check a couple of times more    

Comment: It is working fine with kendo controls too as you can see its saves them as I needed [Stephen](http://prntscr.com/a3vh7z)

Comment: @StephenMuecke please place that as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model for `ModuleList` contains only fields, not properties. Change it to add getter/setter's

```
public class ModuleList
{
    public int? ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
}
```